# Required field display name change issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently doing a little bit of upgrading to a solution 3 upfates of which are display name changes.

I have 3 fields

1. A date field Approved - Required
2. A date field expiry - Required
3. Number - Not Required

I update these fields display names at site level and push the changes down.

The result is that all fields are updated at site level.

Only the Number field gets updated in the site content types.

I'm not getting anything back from the ULS logss, Is this a special feature of SharePoint that you can't update the display names of required fields programmatically?

```
  private void UpdateFieldDisplayNameAndDescription(SPSite site, string fieldStaticName, string newFieldDisplayName, string description, bool isRequired)
    {
        try
        {
            using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
            {
                SPField field = web.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(fieldStaticName);
                if (field != null)
                {
                    field.Title = newFieldDisplayName;
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(description))
                    {
                        field.Description = description;
                    }
                    field.Required = isRequired; // Tried this method without this here also.
                    field.PushChangesToLists = true;
                    field.Update(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Any Ideas

My next step is to make sure that this is also replicated to any content types within lists but don't want to try that until this little niggle is sorted. Any ideas or tips?

I am running this under a custom action(feature upgrade)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for the push down not working for the two required fields is because the XML that defines them has been updated in the projects lifespan, The Number field that was updating correctly has never been changed.